Does the wave function of a group of particles collapse upon a collective measurement?
Say we have 10 electrons in a box. If we measure the spin of an individual electron along some axis, we find it to be spin up or down, but not in between. But what if we measure the combined spin state (like an MRI machine picking up magnetic field from all protons in the body). In that case I assume the result will not necessarily be spin up or down but can instead be anything. Is that correct?

If you have 10 electrons in a box you would not be able to use ten electron models independently, you would have to use one ten-electron model, wouldn't you?

@controlgroup what do you mean by that? The 10 electrons are indistinguishable.

@QPhysl Then it makes no sense to measure the spin of one distinguished electron.

@ZeroTheHero If you have two spins, put each one in a box. This is valid since $\left[\mathbf{r},\mathbf{S}\right]=0$. You are allowed to measure the spin in each box, you don't know which particle you measured because the second quantization tells us they are one field, not distinguishable.

@QPhysl sorry maybe I was not clear: in your example you are not measuring spin 1 or spin 2, you are measuring just one spin.  Maybe I’m reading the question wrong but I’m reading it as measuring a specific spin.

Identical particles are indistinguishable, but let's put one spin-half particle in box $1$ and a second in box $2$. The way they collapse depends on, as you mentioned, whether you measure their total spin or their individual spins (meaning the total spin in each box). If you have two particles, the total spin operator is: $$S^2=S_1^2+2\mathbf{S}_1\cdot\mathbf{S}_2+S_2^2$$ And $S_{1z}$ and $S_{2z}$ clearly don't commute with $S^2$ due to the middle term. If you prepare a spin singlet state: $$\left|0,0\right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>\right)$$
and measure $S_{1z}$ to be up and $S_{2z}$ to be down, then the state collapses to $\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>$ which in terms of the total spin, is: $$\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|0,0\right>+\left|1,0\right>\right)$$
Now if you measure the total spin of the two-box system and find that its magnitude is zero, then your measurement collapses it back to $\left|0,0\right>$. Your 10-electron example is a more complicated extension of this idea. Measurement always causes collapse, but what you're measuring matters since the observables don't commute (i.e., $\left[S^2,S_{jz}\right]\neq0$).

I like your two box system. And in your last statement, basically the fact that these two operators do not commute indicate if I measure the total spin of two boxes then that does not necessarily indicate the individual spins have collapsed into spin up or down.

"Measurement always causes collapse" need not be true! Nobody knows whether the collapse in QM actually happens or is just apparent. If the time evolution in QM is unitary, then what you do in a measurement should in theory be reversible, in some cases even in practice. If the time evolution is not unitary then you may objectively have a collapse, with loss of information. At this moment nobody knows...

@JosBergervoet, this is more of a question of philosophy rather than physics. However, the collapse measurably occurs, as long as we view ourselves and the measurement equipment as having a fixed wavefunction. If we look at a simple model where we are a spin 1/2 particle in a singlet superposition with another spin 1/2 particle, then if we measure the other as spin down, then we view it as collapsing, but an outside viewer would still see us in a spin-singlet until they measure us as well. This is just Schrödinger's cat and doesn't give any contradictions.

You are wrong. Loss of information in QM will be a huge thing if it can be proven! And if there is an objective collapse you should be able to prove it. A Nobel prize will then be your reward, without any, uh... uncertainty, in my view!

Are box 1 and 2 indistinguishable?

@JosBergervoet How is information lost? Each measurement of a closed system makes the system open, causing decoherence. The whole universe can be taken as closed, but then no external measurements can be taken so it is a vacuous truth showing that global information isn't lost (if measurements cause information loss, and the global system can't be measured without introducing some external system, causing the universe not to be closed, then there is no instance when global information is lost). I know very little about quantum information though, so please correct me.

@my2cts You are free to label them differently, if that is what you mean

@QPhysl The whole universe as a closed system will only be free of information loss if you use unitary time evolution (so the people inside who do measurements will only see apparent collapse due to decoherence etc.) If the time evolution is not unitary and the collapse actually happens (which would really alter QM, but some Copenhagen adepts call it their "interpretation" of QM) then what you write no longer is true. There can be information loss in that case. And it would be a huge discovery if this were found to be true.

You write "If we measure the spin of an individual electron along some axis, we find it to be spin up or down". This is strictly speaking only true if "some axis" happens to be the vertical axis. If it is a horizontal axis you might measure for instance "spin right", which is a superposition of spin up and spin down.
If you measure the combined spin of $10$ electrons, you will have a combined spin that can have $11$ values instead of the $2$ possibilities for one electron. But it still cannot "be anything", as you write at the end.
Note also that the $11$ outcomes are not equally likely, since you can combine the $10$ spins to $5$ different total spin values, i.e. eigenvalues of $S_\text{tot}^2$ which are $S_\text{tot}(S_\text{tot}+1)$, where $S_\text{tot}$ can be $0,1,2,3,4$ or $5$. And this can be done in a lot of different ways, more ways for the smaller values than for the largest value ($S_\text{tot}=5$). For the outcome of the spin along some axis ($S_\text{axis}$) this will give for the $11$ discrete possible values an almost Gauss-curve shaped distribution. So there is a much larger chance to find small values like $S_\text{axis}=0$ or $\pm 1$ then to find $\pm 4$ or $\pm 5$.

What's so special about the 'vertical' axis?

The words "up" and "down" that were used by OP, only apply to that axis! You may say it's nitpicking, perhaps, but what OP should have written is that measuring along "some axis" the result is spin $+1/2$ or $-1/2$ (as opposed to saying that the result is up or down).
